# Testing Multi-threaded and non Multi-threaded task scheduling

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, spring-test

i have problem understanding some of my test cases and their results when i am trying to test multi-threaded and non-multi-threaded `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler()`

i have following methods for both scenarios.

```
    private int counter;

    private void increment() {
        counter++;
    }


    public String doWork(final CountDownLatch latch, final int taskNo) {
        System.out.println("running task: " + taskNo);
        latch.countDown();
        increment();
        return taskNo == 1 ? "First" : "Second";
    }
```

basically one of them will have one thread assigned, and the test case would be to schedule two tasks on it, as below:

```
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void shouldNotBeAbleToSimultaneouslyScheduleTest() {
        final var taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("test-");
        taskScheduler.initialize();

        final var latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

        final var inOneSecond = Instant.now().plusSeconds(1);
        final var taskOrders = new ArrayList<String>();
        taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
                    try {
                        Assertions.assertEquals(1, counter); // --> Why it is 1 and not 0?
                        // make thread wait 5 seconds to do increment
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        //increment
                        taskOrders.add(doWork(latch, 1));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

                , inOneSecond);

        taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
                    Assertions.assertEquals(0, counter);
                    //increment
                    taskOrders.add(doWork(latch, 2));
                    // counter should be 1 since only current task is completed
                    Assertions.assertEquals(1, counter);
                }
                , inOneSecond);

        final var bothCompleted = latch.await(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // assert both tasks completed
        Assertions.assertTrue(bothCompleted);
        // assert both tasks incremented it
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, counter);
        // second task was first to run
        Assertions.assertEquals("Second", taskOrders.get(0));
        // first task was second to run
        Assertions.assertEquals("First", taskOrders.get(1));
    }
```

now in this test scenario i wanna understand why in the first task counter is 1, because how i grasp it, is that one thread is doing first task which initially counter is 0 how it can run second task first, while it is in first task?

second scenario is when it `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler()` is assigned to have 2 threads as below:

```
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void shouldSimultaneouslyScheduleTest() {
        final var taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("test-");
        taskScheduler.initialize();

        final var latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        final var inOneSecond = Instant.now().plusSeconds(1);
        final var taskOrders = new ArrayList<String>();
        taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
                    try {
                        Assertions.assertEquals(0, counter); // --> HOW COME HERE counter is 0     but not 1 like previous scenario?
                        // make thread take 5 seconds to complete
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        // increment
                        taskOrders.add(doWork(latch, 1));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

                , inOneSecond);

        taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
                    Assertions.assertEquals(0, counter); // why the counter is zero here ?
                    // increment
                    taskOrders.add(doWork(latch, 2));
                    Assertions.assertEquals(1, counter);
                }
                , inOneSecond);

        final var bothCompleted = latch.await(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // assert both tasks completed
        Assertions.assertTrue(bothCompleted);
        // assert both tasks incremented it
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, counter);
        // second task was first to run
        Assertions.assertEquals("Second", taskOrders.get(0));
        // first task was second to run
        Assertions.assertEquals("First", taskOrders.get(1));
    }
```

in this one i wanna understand how come in both tasks counter is 0?